# Is there a way to dynamically create a Postgres database with go-pg or any method in go generally?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I am working on a project that involves me dynamically creating a database for each client. I could do this with PHP and MySQL, but for optimization, the project language is been changed to Go and PostgreSQL. So i am trying to see if there is a way to achieve this with go-pg or any method in Go.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How does each client's database differ (what is the "dynamic" element here)? Also what have you tried so far or how would you do something like this in PHP/MySQL?

Comment: If you can run SQL statements through Go, you can [create a database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html) provided you can connect as the superuser (but an application should never connect as the superuser - it should simply rely that the database was created before hand)

Comment: It is an utterly wrong approach to create a database for each customer to create multi-tenant capabilities. Instead, adjust your data model.

Comment: +1 to Markus' advice. Dynamically generated tables/schemas are a nightmare. The [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site is a good place to ask questions about how to change your data model.